# how to clear sessionsScope from Xpages with ssjs?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying

```
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
        map.remove( iterator.next() ); 
    }
}
```

but the value pairs in my sessionscope remain there. nothing is cleared or removed

Comment: The code should work, I've used it liberally. It's worth making sure that whatever initialises the sessionScope map isn't running again without you realising it - easy enough to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The function seems correct. 

Are you sure you implement it correctly?

How did you check that the sessionScopes weren't cleaned?
What do you want to do exactly?

The function you used cleans the sessionScope only of the current database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code a little bit to use iterator properly.

```
function clearMap( map:Map ){ // Get iterator for the keys
    var iterator = map.keySet().iterator();  // Remove all items 
    while( iterator.hasNext() ){  
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove(); //call iterator.remove to actually remove item
    }
}
```